# Cookie cut a polygon out of another polygon using JTS only

Tags: geojson, jts-topology-suite

I need to do some surgery on polygons in mongodb

I have a polygon I want to cut from

```
            //this is a test case, in reality i am using mongodb to store geoJsonPolygons..so converting to JTS Geometry here.
                Geometry parent = GeoJsonPolygonUtil.toGeometry(geoJsonPolygonParent);
                
                //Cookie cut this polygon from parent.
                Geometry child = GeoJsonPolygonUtil.toGeometry(geoJsonPolygon);
                
                //create line segments from the polygon we want to cut out..
                Geometry lineSegements = PolygonUtil.polygonize(child);
                
                //split?(cut) out the polygon..
                Geometry parentAfterChildRemoved = PolygonUtil.splitPolygon(parent, lineSegements);
                
                //create a new polygon minus the child to cut out...
                geoJsonPolygonParent = GeoJsonConversionUtil.extract(parentAfterChildRemoved.getCoordinates());
```

I am using the PolygonUtil polygonize, splitPolygon from another gis stack overflow answer thinking it would work...but it does not, the parent polygon has no changes...

[JTS: split arbitrary polygon by a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189976/jts-split-arbitrary-polygon-by-a-line/190002#190002)

Parent Polygon - zipcode 92683
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/4769bc85338e7398dfdf27307b3d381d
[image: parent poygon]

Child Polygon - zipcode 92655
https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/139e7645a59ef7a36aecfe7d42f9beac
[image]

my PolygonUtil code:
public class PolygonUtil {

```
    public static Geometry polygonize(Geometry geometry) {
        List lines = LineStringExtracter.getLines(geometry);
        Polygonizer polygonizer = new Polygonizer();
        polygonizer.add(lines);
        Collection polys = polygonizer.getPolygons();
        Polygon[] polyArray = GeometryFactory.toPolygonArray(polys);
        return geometry.getFactory().createGeometryCollection(polyArray);
    }

    public static Geometry splitPolygon(Geometry poly, Geometry line) {
        Geometry nodedLinework = poly.getBoundary().union(line);
        Geometry polys = polygonize(nodedLinework);

        // Only keep polygons which are inside the input
        List output = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < polys.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
            Polygon candpoly = (Polygon) polys.getGeometryN(i);
            if (poly.contains(candpoly.getInteriorPoint())) {
                output.add(candpoly);
            }
        }
        return poly.getFactory().createGeometryCollection(GeometryFactory.toGeometryArray(output));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your data in a database, or all geojson files?

Comment: Mongodb, stored as geospatial objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the difference method of JTS Geometry.

```
public  Geometry getDifferenceGeometry(Geometry parentGeom, Geometry childGeom ) throws ParseException {
        return  parentGeom.difference(childGeom);
 
    }
```